# Groupby based on a multiple logical conditions applied to a different columns DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':[1,2,3,4,2,42,12,21,21,424,34,12,42],
'type':['big','small','medium','big','big','big','big','medium','small','small','small','medium','small'],
'entity':['R','R','R','P','R','P','P','P','R','R','P','R','R']})

    value    type  entity
0       1     big       R
1       2   small       R
2       3  medium       R
3       4     big       P
4       2     big       R
5      42     big       P
6      12     big       P
7      21  medium       P
8      21   small       R
9     424   small       R
10     34   small       P
11     12  medium       R
12     42   small       R
```

The operation consists of grouping by column 'entity' doing a count operation based on a two logical conditions applied to a column 'value' and column 'type'. In my case, I have to count the values greater than 3 in the column 'name' and are not equal to 'medium' in the column 'type'. The result must be R=3 and P=4. After this, I must add the result to the original dataframe creating a new column named ‘Count’.
I know this operation can be done in R with the next code:

```
df[y!='medium' & value>3 , new_var:=.N,by=entity]
df[is.na(new_var),new_var:=0,]
df[,new_var:=max(new_var),by=entity]
```

In a previous task, I had to calculate only the values greater than 3 as condition. In that case, the result was R=3 and P=4 and I got it applying the next code:

```
In []:  df.groupby(['entity'])['value'].apply(lambda x: (x>3).sum())

Out[]:  entity
        P    5
        R    4
        Name: value, dtype: int64

In []:  DF=pd.DataFrame(DF)
In []:  DF.reset_index(inplace=True)
In []:  df.merge(DF,on=['entity'],how='inner')
In []:  df=df.rename(columns={'value_x':'value','value_y':'count'},inplace=True)
Out[]:  

    value   type     entity  count
0      1     big          R      4
1      2   small          R      4
2      3  medium          R      4
3      2     big          R      4
4     21   small          R      4
5    424   small          R      4
6     12  medium          R      4
7     42   small          R      4
8      4     big          P      5
9     42     big          P      5
10    12     big          P      5
11    21  medium          P      5
12    34   small          P      5
```

My questions are: How do I do it for the two conditions case? In fact, How do I do it for a general case with multiples different conditions?

Comment: That R (data.table) code could be simplified to `df[, new_var := max(.N * (y != 'medium' & value > 3)), by=entity]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create mask by your conditions - here for greater by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) with not equal by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) chained by `&` for bitwise `AND` and then use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for count `True`s by `sum`:

```
mask = df['value'].gt(3) & df['type'].ne('medium')
df['count'] = mask.groupby(df['entity']).transform('sum')
```

Solution with helper column `new`:

```
mask = df['value'].gt(3) & df['type'].ne('medium')
df['count'] = df.assign(new = mask).groupby('entity')['new'].transform('sum')
```

---

```
print (df)
    value    type entity  count
0       1     big      R      3
1       2   small      R      3
2       3  medium      R      3
3       4     big      P      4
4       2     big      R      3
5      42     big      P      4
6      12     big      P      4
7      21  medium      P      4
8      21   small      R      3
9     424   small      R      3
10     34   small      P      4
11     12  medium      R      3
12     42   small      R      3
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This answer gives me a solution for a several similar tasks more.

Answer (score 2):

The solution in Pandas is superb. This is an alternative in a different package. The reason I am throwing this in here is because the original code was in `data.table` in R, and it might be useful for others, who probably want a similar solution within Python.

This is a solution in [pydatatable](https://github.com/h2oai/datatable), a library that aims to replicate `data.table` in python. Note that it is not as feature rich as Pandas; hopefully, with time, more features will be added.

Create the frame with `datatable` :

```
   from datatable import dt, f, by, update

    df = dt.Frame({'value':[1,2,3,4,2,42,12,21,21,424,34,12,42],
'type':['big','small','medium','big','big','big','big','medium','small','small','small','medium','small'],
'entity':['R','R','R','P','R','P','P','P','R','R','P','R','R']})
```

Create the condition - In datatable, the `f` symbol is a shortcut to refer to the dataframe:

```
condition = (f.type!="medium") & (f.value>3)
```

The syntax below should be familiar to users of `data.table`,

```
 DT[i, j, by]
```

where `i` refers to anything that can occur in the rows, `j` refers to column operations, and `by` is for grouping operations. The [update](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dt/update.html#datatable.update) function is similar in function to the `:=` function in `data.table`; it allows for creation of new columns or update of existing columns in place.

```
df[:, update(count=dt.sum(condition)), by('entity')]

df

 value  type    entity  count
0   1   big     R       3
1   2   small   R       3
2   3   medium  R       3
3   4   big     P       4
4   2   big     R       3
5   42  big     P       4
6   12  big     P       4
7   21  medium  P       4
8   21  small   R       3
9   424 small   R       3
10  34  small   P       4
11  12  medium  R       3
12  42  small   R       3
```

Comment: Awesome!. 
In these cases, this alternative lets the people who know well R gets a good solution. Thank you!